# To Find Check box Checked in GridViewRow

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can we verify whether check box is checked in each row of GridView. This below code is not working.

```
             $("#btnComplete").click(
                            function(e) {
                                $("#<%=grdCustDetails.ClientID%> tr").each(function() {
                                    //Skip first(header) row
                                    if (!this.rowIndex) return;


                                    if ($(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').checked > 0) {
                                        alert("your check box in this row is checked");
                                    }



                                });

              });
```

Comment: There is a check box named with chkSel in each row of the Gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
    alert("your check box in this row is checked");
}
```

You can also use `is` method like this

```
if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    alert("your check box in this row is checked");
}
```